# HTML CSS: Side Page Component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the proper Web combonent name for this? Is it Card, Caption? And Does CSS Bootrap have a component for this? Our Customers wants to build a web component as designed below. An Image with Title Description.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific CSS component in Bootstrap that can match with your image but you can use some CSS style from Bootstrap.
you can try this and change title side CSS according to your requirement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row" style="height: 100px;" >
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:lavender;">
    <img src="img.png" class="align-self-center mr-3"style="position: absolute;top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #b3b2b2;text-align: center;">
    <p style="position: absolute;top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">title<p/></div>
    

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not at the side, and doesnt even answer question?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use this

    <div class="media">
      <img src="img.png" class="align-self-center mr-3" style="width:60px">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>use this </p>

      </div>
    </div>



or


<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <img src="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <h2 class="bg-secondary text-white">title</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that puts the title in the bottom, and does not even answer question

Comment: first example is image is in center then text content is in left will come

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_media_alignment&stacked=h